# $scope not defined inside function called from popup

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

i don't know why i can't access to $scope inside $scope.menuPopUpDelete, i need to delete the clicked trip in the popup.
$scope.trips is not a global variable inside the controller??
I would appreciate some help please!

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="mytripsController">
 <ul class="my-trips-list" style="padding-bottom: 100px;" ng-model="trips">
 <li class="my-trip-item module" ng-repeat="trip in trips" >
    <div class="list-image">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Beach_pano.jpg">
        <h1>{{trip.title}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="list-content">
        <div class="menu-points" ng-click="showMenuPopUp($event)">
            <img src="images/menu-points.png"/>
            <div class="popup-menu" style="display: none">
                <div ng-click="menuPopUpDeleteClicked($event,$index)">Eliminar</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
   </body>
```

JS:

```
 var mytrips = angular.module('mytrips',[]);
 mytrips.controller('mytripsController', function ($scope) {
$scope.trips = [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "title":"Plan de viaje Mallorca",
        "island": "Mallorca",
        "duration": "3",
        "startDate":"19/10/2014",
        "endDate":"21/10/2014",
        "image":"fotoTrips.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "title":"Plan de viaje Mallorca2",
        "island": "Mallorca",
        "duration": "3",
        "startDate":"19/10/2014",
        "endDate":"21/10/2014",
        "image":"fotoTrips.jpg"
    }

];

$scope.showMenuPopUp = function($event){
    var $popup = $($event.currentTarget).find('.popup-menu');
    $popup.show('fast',function(){
        $('body').click(function(){
            $popup.hide();
            $(this).unbind("click");
        });
    });
}
$scope.menuPopUpDeleteClicked = function($event,$index){
}
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is more with the way you have your HTML structured than anything else. You clicks are getting gobbled up and never executed.
Try this, which seems to work just fine.

```
    <div class="menu-points" ng-click="showMenuPopUp('popup1')">
        <img src="images/menu-points.png"/>
    </div>
        <div id='popup1' class="popup-menu" style="display: none">
            <div ng-click="menuPopUpDeleteClicked($event,$index)">Eliminar</div>
        </div>

   $scope.showMenuPopUp = function(name){
    var $popup = $('#'+name);
    $popup.show('fast',function(){
      $('body').click(function(){
          $popup.hide();
          $(this).unbind("click");
      });
    });
   }
   $scope.menuPopUpDeleteClicked = function($event,$index){
     console.log("inside here");
     console.log($scope.trips);
   }
```

Note that the popup is taken OUT of the enclosing div as the click event was getting gobbled up. The name of the popup we are popping up is passed in instead of the event.